# Does this "count" is a mutation?

Tags: sml

```
fun count_wcs p =
    let
        val count = 0
    in
        g (fn () => count + 1) (fn y => 1) p
    end
```

I'm doing homework and we're not supposed to use mutations, this doesn't reassign the value to anything but it doesn't feel right. Please, don't say what is the right way to do this, because I'm supposed to figure this out.

```
datatype pattern = Wildcard
         | Variable of string
         | UnitP
         | ConstP of int
         | TupleP of pattern list
         | ConstructorP of string * pattern

fun g f1 f2 p =
    let
    val r = g f1 f2
    in
    case p of
        Wildcard          => f1 ()
      | Variable x        => f2 x
      | TupleP ps         => List.foldl (fn (p,i) => (r p) + i) 0 ps
      | ConstructorP(_,p) => r p
      | _                 => 0
    end
```

This function g has to receive a type unit -> int function as the first argument. I checked the count after I called the function and got 0, so it is ok to write it like this, right? But still, it does feel sloppy.

Added the context (function g and the datatype used). The function count_wcs is supposed to count the number a Wildcard pattern appears in a pattern.

Comment: You can't check the value of `count` after calling the function, since the binding is local to the function. I'm guessing you have another thing also called "count", but that's not this "count" (read about bindings and scope in your book).

Comment: The function actually returns the value of count (it creates another count value inside its scope, and I think it uses shadowing to return the number of calls) after the g function call ends. I'll change the function name and put more info on the context.

Comment: It doesn't return the value of `count` – every single one of your `count`s is `0`. It returns the sum of the number of wildcards and the number of variables (since both your functions return `1`) – which is a bug – as added up by the `foldl`.

Comment: You're right, it's `foldl` who does the magic. I messed up on this one, that count isn't even needed, the functions just need to return 1 and 0 to count the Wildcards. Thanks! I was still trying to understand what was happening. `fun count_wcs p = g (fn () => 1) (fn y => 0) p ` I changed it to this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not count as a mutation, but it does resemble what you might do if you had them and is probably not going to work, depending on what it is you're doing. Mutations require *references* and they're made with `ref` and are de-referenced with `!`. So just stick away from those. :-)

You're doing something that will be of little benefit:

> ```
> let
>   val count = 0
> in
>   ...
> end
> ```

will bind `count` to 0, but will never cause `count` to have any other value; I presume that you want to eventually have that `count` increases. If it had been a reference, `val count = ref 0`, you could increment it by doing `count := !count + 1`, but since it's not, you have to make `count` a variable of some function for it to change.

For example:

```
fun count_4s ([],    count) = count
  | count_4s (x::xs, count) = count_4s (xs, if x = 4 then count + 1 else count)
```

In each call `count` is constant, but in each subsequent, recursive call it is possibly incremented.

> This function g has to receive a type *unit -> int* function as first argument.
>
> ```
> ...
> g (fn () => count + 1) (fn y => 1) p
> ...
> ```
>
> *[...]* But still it does feel sloppy.

Assuming that `g`'s first arguments have no side-effects and do not throw exceptions and do not loop forever, all they can do is return the same thing on every call. This makes them rather boring. Typically functions that either take as input or return `() : unit` do something else, like read or write from a source external to the program.

I wouldn't call it sloppy. Just a bit weird, without knowing the context.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to identify mutation in standard ML - if you don't use `ref` variables and assign them new values with `:=`, it's not mutation.
And you don't, so you aren't mutating anything.

Also, your function can be simplified to

```
fun count_wildcards p = g (fn () => 1) (fn _ => 1) p
```

which makes it even clearer that nothing gets mutated.
(It's not at all clear what it's supposed to accomplish, so it's impossible to tell whether your solution is correct.)